# Journey validation error - Scheduling automation unsuccessful: Add a start date that's in the future

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

For this journey, this is the version 7.
When I tried to change the scheduling type from "Run Once" to "Run daily for 3 times", although I set the datetime to future datetime (12.30pm GMT vs current datetime GMT is 11.58am), but it doesn't allow me to save or activate the journey. Does anyone know what's exactly the issue?

[image: GMT time now]

[image: Validation Error]

Comment: Sometimes Journey might get stuck with old data on the backend and it simply requires re-selection of the configuration or re-creation of the journey at max.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would think so, when I re-create a new journey and it works now.